# Why do chipped people obey A.L.I.E?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-100

There is something I do not understand in the series **The 100**. There is all this stuff about the City of Light, and the chipped people who obey ALIE.

However, I do not understand why they obey her. I know that she removes pain and emotion, but, as we can see, she does not control them directly, but tells them what to do. However people still have the memories of before they were chipped, like when Jasper enumerates all the deaths, and they remember that they were fighting A.L.I.E. So why do they not rebel, like Raven did?

It is because they are happy of their conditions? Because they do not see the point of fighting A.L.I.E?

At one moment, Thelonious said to A.L.I.E that she should remove their free will, so what were the changes done after Raven rebelled that did not allow people to rebel again?

Comment: Thanks for the edit cde, english is not my mother langage :) Just one question, why can't I write in the title the name of the series/film?

Comment: It's unneeded. There is no other A.L.I.E. in movies or tv, the 100 tag is used, and the first sentence already has it. It's just how it's done around here.

Comment: The memories aren't fresh enough at my head to give a good answer, however, I do believe it was more about manipulating their feelings saying that their friends wanted to destroy the City of Light which brought them happiness.

Answer (score 1):

The chip that they take is actually embedding into the base of their brain and it is both removing pain and negative emotion by turning off those receptors, but it is also giving ALIE control of those who've taken it because she's practically code running their brain.

> We learn more about this later in the series when Raven discovers EMPing her chip still left code residue in her brain that was giving her access to more knowledge and brain power.

At the end of the day, ALIE is a computer program and essentially runs people via code that's implanted through the chip.

Comment: I don't think that's it. As he said, A.L.I.E. was against controlling their free will, at first.

Comment: At first, but once people accepted the chip it was essentially giving up the free will and allowing her control. That's why they tortured people into giving consent.

Comment: It was pretty clear that ALIE was able to override free will..